# Is there firebase realtime database server logs exists?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I faced a problem with my app using Firebase Realtime Database. At some point of time one of the user data records was like a wiped out of my database and I have no idea how it could happen.

So my question is: is there any way to get some kind of firebase server logs to find out what happened, what requests of my app caused data loss. Right now I couldn't find any history in Firebase console.

If there are no history then what should I do to investigate such cases in future? Some suggestions/practices? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no server side logging, history, or auditing available to developers in Realtime Database.  There's really nothing you can do to investigate using tools provided by Firebase.  You need to have your own auditing or backups in place.

Comment: Nothing except [profiling your database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/profile) and adding something like [Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging)?

Answer (score 1):

I'll preface my answer by saying that every developer should carefully consider their actions when dealing with user data, even if it's doing something well-intentioned like making backups to prevent data loss. Some clients might be storing potentially sensitive information and will want to know that if they delete something in their client app, the data will be permanently removed from the database and not be sitting on another server somewhere (or on somebody's laptop) as part of a backup. However, I don't know your situation so this extra consideration may not apply to you at all.

With that in mind, if you just want a one-time download of a simple file containing all the data in the database, navigate to the [Firebase web console](https://console.firebase.google.com) and click on your project. Then under the Develop heading in the sidebar choose Database>Realtime Database. Then click the button with the three vertical dots in the upper right hand corner of your database and choose Export JSON. Then save the file and you will have a local copy of the entire realtime database.

If you require more frequent backups, then you should read the [documentation for the Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) and from there you can create a script that can retrieve data each time a certain event occurs, such as a new user getting added to the database. The actual structure of your script will depend on the way your database is set up and the requirements of your clients/users.